# Backreference non capture group in javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

This is going to be a really short question...

Lets assume I have a regex like:

```
(Hello)(?:fooBar)
```

How can I backreference it using \2? I know this works with normal capturing groups and that a non capturing group only groups tokens together but if there is any work-around then I would be glad to know.

**Edit:** Problem is:

I need to backreference to non capturing groups sometimes. For example there are moments where I really dont want that group to show up as a match but it shows up multiple times in the pattern which is why I prefer to backreference it.

Comment: Try adding a second empty capturing group - `(Hello)(?:fooBar)()`. Or an outer group: `((Hello)(?:fooBar))`. Or `((Hello))(?:fooBar)`, `(Hello)((?:fooBar))`, etc. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew didnt know this question was bad quality. Isnt it clear what im asking?

Comment: What are you asking for? What is the real problem? Please clarify.

Comment: That is not possible to backreference a non-capturing group as it does not create any memory buffers with the captured texts.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ya, I thought so, that is really unfortunate but oh well. At least my doubts are gone now xD.

Comment: If the idea is to create a [subroutine](http://www.regular-expressions.info/subroutine.html) so as not to write the subpattern several times, you can't do that either.

Comment: @Mariano guess im really out of luck unless I create my own regex engine which already passed through my mind.

Comment: Replace the splitting approach with a *matching* one if you are using a pattern with capturing groups in the `split` method. You have not revealed the real problem you are dealing with. There is no point reinventing the wheel when you really have all the tools at hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, a backreference applies only to a capture group.

But it sounds like your actual concern is with not repeating yourself. In this case, you can construct the regex:

```
const f = 'foobar';
const r = new RegExp(`Hello${f}blah${f}blah${f}blah`);
```

Comment: Actually you are right. It should have crossed my mind. I hardly used the regex object.